# Removing [ ] and " " from values across a large data table

Tags: r, data-cleaning, gsub

I have a large dataframe (secondary data analysis) with ~300 variables and 1500 observations. The dataset contains [] and " " in both the **column names** and the actual **values**.

How can I modify the gsub function or use a similar function to remove the [] and " " from the actual **values**.

For example, I have a column in the data_HH dataframe called **Nights_slept_ouside**, where one of the values is given as **["One night"]**. I would like to change this to **One night**

I have multiple similar examples of different values in different variables scattered throughout the dataframe.

I have used the following code to successfully remove the [] and " " from the **column** names, **but it did not work with the values in the rows**.

Trying to rename the values did not work because the [] and "" characters in the actual value names seemed to be confusing R.

```
data_HH <- fread("ICEMRCambodia_Households.txt")
names(data_HH) <-  gsub(" ", "_", gsub("\\[|\\]", "", names(data_HH)))
```

Here is the output from dput(head(data_HH))

```
> dput(head(data_HH))
structure(list(Household_ID = c("h_2001", "h_2002", "h_2003", 
"h_2004", "h_2005", "h_2006"), Household_data_collection_date_EUPATH_0021085 = c("[\"2017-12-", 
"[\"2017-12-", "[\"2017-11-", "[\"2017-12-", "[\"2017-12-", "[\"2017-12-"
), Roof_material_EUPATH_0000003 = c("[\"Corrugated iron\"]", 
"[\"Corrugated iron\"]", "[\"Corrugated iron\"]", "[\"Other\",\"Tent\"]", 
"[\"Corrugated iron\"]", "[\"Corrugated iron\"]"), Floor_material_EUPATH_0000006 = c("Wood", 
"Wood", "Wood", "Wood", "Polished wood", "Wood"), Wall_material_EUPATH_0000009 = c("[\"Wood\"]", 
"[\"Wood\"]", "[\"Wood\"]", "[\"Other\",\"Tent\"]", "[\"Wood\"]", 
"[\"Wood\"]"), Window_material_EUPATH_0025049 = c("No windows", 
"No windows", "No windows", "No windows", "No windows", "No windows"
), Elevated_house_EUPATH_0057707 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE), No_GPS_signal_EUPATH_0057900 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), Respondant_head_of_household_EUPATH_0058084 = c(FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), Other_human_waste_facilities_EUPATH_0025107 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), `No_facility/bush/field_EUPATH_0031063` = c("[\"Yes\"]", 
"[\"Yes\"]", "[\"Yes\"]", "[\"Yes\"]", "[\"Yes\"]", ""), Open_pit_latrine_EUPATH_0031064 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), Closet_over_river_EUPATH_0057708 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), Own_flush_toilet_EUPATH_0057709 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), Own_pit_latrine_with_slab_EUPATH_0057710 = c("[\"No\"]", 
"[\"No\"]", "[\"No\"]", "[\"No\"]", "[\"No\"]", ""), Shared_flush_toilet_EUPATH_0057711 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), Shared_open_pit_latrine_EUPATH_0057712 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), Shared_pit_latrine_with_slab_EUPATH_0057713 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), Main_drinking_water_source_EUPATH_0010099 = c("[\"Surface water (river, pond, irrigation, channel)\"]", 
"[\"Surface water (river, pond, irrigation, channel)\"]", "[\"Surface water (river, pond, irrigation, channel)\"]", 
"[\"Open well (public/private)\"]", "[\"Other\",\"Bottled water\"]", 
""), Time_to_water_source_EUPATH_0037013 = c("Between 5 and 10 minutes", 
"Between 5 and 10 minutes", "Less than 5 minutes", "Less than 5 minutes", 
"Less than 5 minutes", ""), Bednet_count_EUPATH_0020225 = c("[3]", 
"[3]", "[2]", "[1]", "[2]", ""), Bednets_used_count_EUPATH_0057727 = c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA), Bednet_last_night_EUPATH_0058076 = c("Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", ""), Bednet_source_EUPATH_0058077 = c("[\"Purchased in store\"]", 
"[\"Hospital / health center\"]", "[\"Hospital / health center\"]", 
"[\"Hospital / health center\"]", "[\"Purchased in store\"]", 
""), Treated_bednet_count_EUPATH_0057764 = c(0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
0L, NA), `Time_owned_personal_bednet_(years)_EUPATH_0058091` = c(0.417, 
2, 1, 2, 3, NA), Reason_for_no_household_bednets_EUPATH_0058090 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), It_is_too_hot_under_the_net_EUPATH_0058094 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), No_mosquitoes_around_EUPATH_0058095 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), Net_expired_or_damaged_EUPATH_0057883 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), Net_spared_or_reserved_EUPATH_0057884 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), No_malaria_EUPATH_0057885 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), User_did_not_sleep_here_EUPATH_0057886 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), `Don't_know_EUPATH_0058093` = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), Other_EUPATH_0058097 = c("No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", ""), Hammock_count_EUPATH_0057728 = c("[1]", 
"[0]", "[1]", "[1]", "[0]", ""), Hammocks_used_count_EUPATH_0057735 = c("[1]", 
"[0]", "[1]", "[1]", "[0]", ""), Treated_hammock_count_EUPATH_0057765 = c("[0]", 
"[0]", "[1]", "[1]", "[0]", ""), Sprayed_in_past_12_months_EUPATH_0053214 = c("[\"No\"]", 
"[\"No\"]", "[\"No\"]", "[\"No\"]", "[\"No\"]", ""), Received_malaria_information_in_past_3_months_EUPATH_0057714 = c("No", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", ""), Other_household_reason_for_not_using_a_bednet_EUPATH_0057722 = c("", 
"", "", "", "", ""), Persons_living_in_house_count_EUPATH_0000019 = c(4L, 
6L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 1L), Buffalo_count_EUPATH_0057702 = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), Cat_count_EUPATH_0057703 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), Cattle_count_EUPATH_0022195 = c(NA, 
8L, 2L, 12L, 0L, NA), Chicken_count_EUPATH_0022197 = c("[10]", 
"[60]", "[4]", "[20]", "[13]", ""), Dog_count_EUPATH_0037004 = c("[2]", 
"[2]", "[0]", "[6]", "[2]", ""), Duck_count_EUPATH_0022198 = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), Goat_count_EUPATH_0037005 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Goose_count_EUPATH_0057704 = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), Monkey_count_EUPATH_0057705 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Pig_count_EUPATH_0022199 = c(NA, 
8L, 0L, 12L, 0L, NA), Rabbit_count_EUPATH_0057706 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Main_source_of_income_EUPATH_0058085 = c("[\"Farming\"]", 
"[\"Farming\"]", "[\"Farming\"]", "[\"Farming\"]", "[\"Farming\"]", 
""), Sleep_under_a_mosquito_net_EUPATH_0058098 = c("Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", ""), Spray_insecticide_inside_the_house_EUPATH_0058099 = c("[\"No\"]", 
"[\"No\"]", "[\"No\"]", "[\"No\"]", "[\"No\"]", ""), Do_not_know_EUPATH_0058078 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), Avoid_mosquito_bites_EUPATH_0057862 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), Burn_dry_lime_skin_EUPATH_0057863 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), Clear_grass_around_household_EUPATH_0057864 = c("No", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", ""), Drain_or_treat_stagnant_water_EUPATH_0057865 = c("Yes", 
"No", "No", "No", "Yes", ""), Eat_well_and_drink_clean_water_and_good_health_EUPATH_0057866 = c("No", 
"Yes", "No", "No", "No", ""), Electric_raquette_EUPATH_0057867 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), Television_EUPATH_0057882 = c("[\"No\"]", 
"[\"No\"]", "[\"No\"]", "[\"No\"]", "[\"No\"]", ""), Keep_clothes_and_body_clean_EUPATH_0057868 = c("No", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", ""), Keep_inside_household_clean_EUPATH_0057869 = c("[\"Yes\"]", 
"[\"No\"]", "[\"No\"]", "[\"No\"]", "[\"No\"]", ""), Keep_outside_household_clean_EUPATH_0057870 = c("[\"Yes\"]", 
"[\"Yes\"]", "[\"No\"]", "[\"No\"]", "[\"No\"]", ""), Smoke_tobacco_EUPATH_0057871 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), Take_preventative_herbs_EUPATH_0057872 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), Turn_on_fan_EUPATH_0057873 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), Use_insecticide_on_self_EUPATH_0057874 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), Use_mosquito_coils_EUPATH_0057875 = c("[\"No\"]", 
"[\"No\"]", "[\"No\"]", "[\"No\"]", "[\"No\"]", ""), Other_EUPATH_0058096 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), Friends_or_relatives_EUPATH_0058079 = c("[\"No\"]", 
"[\"No\"]", "[\"Yes\"]", "[\"Yes\"]", "[\"No\"]", ""), `Non-governmental_organization_(NGO)_EUPATH_0058086` = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), Radio_EUPATH_0058089 = c("[\"No\"]", 
"[\"No\"]", "[\"Yes\"]", "[\"Yes\"]", "[\"No\"]", ""), Community_meeting_EUPATH_0057876 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), Healthcare_worker_EUPATH_0057877 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), Household_visit_EUPATH_0057878 = c("No", 
"No", "Yes", "No", "No", ""), Insert_in_mosquito_net_package_EUPATH_0057879 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), Net_distribution_event_EUPATH_0057880 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), Poster_EUPATH_0058088 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", ""), Other_EUPATH_0058087 = c("No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", ""), Other_household_malaria_knowledge_source_EUPATH_0057729 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Household_data_collection_date_EUPATH_0021085 = c("[\"2017-12-", 
"[\"2017-12-", "[\"2017-11-", "[\"2017-12-", "[\"2017-12-", "[\"2017-12-"
), Village = c("Poucha", "Poucha", "Poucha", "Poucha", "Poucha", 
"Poucha"), Hamlet_EUPATH_0057901 = c("Group 4", "Group 4", "Group 4", 
"Group 4", "Group 4", "Group 4")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x1570156e0>)
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

**Brief update here - mainly for novices like myself who might find this helpful.**

The original solution provided by Mark below did work. I did not realise at first that I needed to run the code multiple times, one time for each column (the values in each column) that I wanted to adjust. So, for example, I ran the following code (and many other similar code lines)

```
data_HH <- mutate(data_HH, Nights_slept_elsewhere = str_replace_all(Nights_slept_elsewhere, "\\[|\\]|\"", ""))
data_HH <- mutate(data_HH, Transport_to_health_facility = str_replace_all(Transport_to_health_facility, "\\[|\\]|\"", ""))
data_HH <- mutate(data_HH, Roof_material = str_replace_all(Roof_material, "\\[|\\]|\"", ""))
data_HH <- mutate(data_HH, Wall_material = str_replace_all(Wall_material, "\\[|\\]|\"", ""))
```

The other solution has worked perfectly, too - I first needed to convert the data.table to a data.frame - then the simple one line of code provided by GKi has worked.

```
i <- sapply(data_HH, is.character)
data_HH[i] <- lapply(data_HH[i], gsub, pattern='[]["]', replacement="")
```

Comment: Hi  Trypanosoma! Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: if you could run dput(data_HH), and add the results to your question, that would be great!

Comment: Hi @Mark, thank you for trying to help. I am currently working with both the suggested solutions but my ignorance is slowing me down a bit. I ran the dput() function as you have suggested but the output is so long it did not seem appropriate to copy it here.

Comment: in that case, `dput(head(data_HH))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
    x = "[\"One night\"]")

mutate(df, x = str_replace_all(x, "\\[|\\]|\"", ""))
          x
1 One night
```

Update: using the dataframe that you included:

```
data_HH <- data_HH %>%
  # the column names aren't unique, so we run it through this so they can be cleaned up
  as_tibble(.name_repair = "universal") %>% 

  # remove all the quotes and square brackets in every column
  mutate(df, across(everything(), ~str_remove_all(., "[\"\\[\\]]")))
```

Comment: Hi @Mark, I am struggling to succeed with this code. I am not sure what I am doing wrong (my inexperience) and as this is my first time posting in this particular forum I am not sure if I should add my failed attempts to the original question or add to the comment box here.

Comment: add the output of dput(head(data_HH)) to your question

Comment: OK. @Mark. I have added the output as you suggested.

Comment: Sorry about this, but it has not changed any of the values in the rows at all. I am trying to change the "values" in the rows. I have managed to change the column names/variables using the sub function. It is the values in the rows I am trying to change.

Comment: hmm odd! I don't know what is going on. That removed the characters in the example you gave.

Comment: It changed the column names but not the values in the columns - I will keep working on it - I am sure it is my error somewhere. Thank you.

Comment: i don't know what else I can do? I think in this case I would give 2 options (considering GKi doesn't seem to have much success either): 1. start with something smaller- instead of parsing the entire file, start with parsing one line, or even one string. Then build up from there. or 2. clean up the input file before you turn it into a dataframe (it looks like it's a bunch of arrays, maybe you could open the file they're in and do a find and replace?

Comment: I thank you for your perseverance and patience. I will keep working on it, applying all the suggested solutions, and report back once I have worked it out. ... hopefully!

Comment: Your original solution has worked - I was doing something wrong. I will clean up my question and provide an updated sample answer shortly. Thanks again

Comment: all good! I'm so glad we got there in the end @Trypanosoma - I was beginning to lose hope!

Answer (score 3):

`[]["]` could be used in `gsub` to remove `[`, `]` and `"`.

```
s <- '["One night"]'
s
#[1] "[\"One night\"]"

gsub('[]["]', "", s)
#[1] "One night"
```

---

For the given data maybe use the following:

```
i <- sapply(data_HH, is.character)
data_HH[i] <- lapply(data_HH[i], gsub, pattern='[]["]', replacement="")
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I am currently working with both the suggested solutions, but my inexperience is still a hindrance. I managed to get your gsub code to work, but the output only printed to the console. When I tried to save it as a new object/dataframe it did not work. How can I modify the code so that it changes the datatable? Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the update. Hope this is what you want.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, but that only gave me the following error message: Error in `[.data.table`(data_HH, i) : 
  i evaluates to a logical vector length 87 but there are 349 rows. Recycling of logical i is no longer allowed as it hides more bugs than is worth the rare convenience. Explicitly use rep(...,length=.N) if you really need to recycle.

Comment: Oh yes. In your `dput` you have a `data.table` and not a `data.frame`. But In the header you write *data frame*.  Maybe convert the `data.table` to a `data.frame` with: `data_HH <- as.data.frame(data_HH)` and the code I showed will work. Or you use `data_HH <- list2DF(lapply(data_HH, \(s) if(is.character(s)) gsub('[]["]', "", s) else s))` .

Comment: Yessssss, this is brilliant, thank you. Sorry for my error in not recognising the subtle importance of the data.table-data.frame distinction. I will update the header accordingly. This has worked PERFECTLY in one simple line of code. Magic!